# Under what circumstances are monadic computations tail-recursive?

Tags: haskell, monads, tail-recursion

In Haskell Wiki's [Recursion in a monad](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Recursion_in_a_monad) there is an example that is claimed to be [tail-recursive](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Tail_recursion):

```
f 0 acc = return (reverse acc)
f n acc = do
    v  <- getLine
    f (n-1) (v : acc)
```

While the imperative notation leads us to believe that it is tail-recursive, it's not so obvious at all (at least to me). If we de-sugar `do` we get

```
f 0 acc = return (reverse acc)
f n acc = getLine >>= \v -> f (n-1) (v : acc)
```

and rewriting the second line leads to

```
f n acc = (>>=) getLine (\v -> f (n-1) (v : acc))
```

So we see that `f` occurs inside the second argument of `>>=`, not in a tail-recursive position. We'd need to examine `IO`'s `>>=` to get an answer.
Clearly **having the recursive call as the last line in a `do` block isn't a sufficient condition a function to be tail-recursive.**

---

Let's say that a *monad is tail-recursive* iff every recursive function in this monad defined as

```
f = do
    ...
    f ...
```

or equivalently

```
f ...  =  (...) >>= \x -> f ...
```

is tail-recursive. My question is:

1. What monads are tail-recursive?
2. Is there some general rule that we can use to immediately distinguish tail-recursive monads?

---

**Update:** Let me make a specific counter-example: The `[]` monad is not tail-recursive according to the above definition. If it were, then

```
f 0 acc = acc
f n acc = do
    r <- acc
    f (n - 1) (map (r +) acc)
```

would have to be tail-recursive. However, desugaring the second line leads to

```
f n acc = acc >>= \r -> f (n - 1) (map (r +) acc)
        = (flip concatMap) acc (\r -> f (n - 1) (map (r +) acc))
```

Clearly, this isn't tail-recursive, and IMHO cannot be made. The reason is that the recursive call isn't the end of the computation. It is performed several times and the results are combined to make the final result.

Comment: Just a quick note: that *is* tail recursive.  Tail recursion simply means that the return value of the last function call is not used by the function.  In your case, the value of the final `f` call is not used.  If you'd rather think of it pragmatically, a function is tail-recursive, if, once you do the last call in it, you can dispose of all the context associated with the function.  Also, as far as I know, there isn't anything inherently tail-recursive or not-tail-recursive about any monad.

Comment: @scvalex While intuitively this makes sense, I'd like to have it formally justified. Could you show that `f` is tail-recursive according to the criteria stated in [Tail recursion](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Tail_recursion)?

Comment: @hammar The definition doesn't care if you can define a recursive function not of that form. It only cares that if an arbitrary function is of that form is tail-recursive or not.

Comment: Can't you just inline the definition of `>>=` and see if the result is tail-recursive?

Comment: @PetrPudlák Looking at the definition on that page, I have to say that `f` is *not* tail-recursive.  On the other hand, I don't agree with that definition as it seems to exclude calling any other function as the first step of expanding the function.  By that definition, `f = f $ 1` is not tail-recursive.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A monadic computation that refers to itself is never tail-recursive.  However, in Haskell you have laziness and corecursion, and that is what counts.  Let's use this simple example:

```
forever :: (Monad m) => m a -> m b
forever c' = let c = c' >> c in c
```

Such a computation runs in constant space if and only if `(>>)` is nonstrict in its second argument.  This is really very similar to lists and `repeat`:

```
repeat :: a -> [a]
repeat x = let xs = x : xs in xs
```

Since the `(:)` constructor is nonstrict in its second argument this works and the list can be traversed, because you have a finite weak-head normal form (WHNF).  As long as the consumer (for example a list fold) only ever asks for the WHNF this works and runs in constant space.

The consumer in the case of `forever` is whatever interprets the monadic computation.  If the monad is `[]`, then `(>>)` is non-strict in its second argument, when its first argument is the empty list.  So `forever []` will result in `[]`, while `forever [1]` will diverge.  In the case of the `IO` monad the interpreter is the very run-time system itself, and there you can think of `(>>)` being always non-strict in its second argument.

Answer (score 5):

What really matters is constant stack space. Your first example is [tail recursive modulo cons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call#Tail_recursion_modulo_cons), thanks to the laziness.

The `(getLine >>=)` will be executed and will evaporate, leaving us again with the call to `f`. What matters is, this happens in a constant number of steps - there's no thunk build-up.

Your second example,

```
f 0 acc = acc
f n acc = concat [ f (n - 1) $ map (r +) acc | r <- acc]
```

will be only linear (in `n`) in its thunk build-up, as the result list is accessed from the left (again due to the laziness, as `concat` is non-strict). If it is consumed at the head it can run in O(1) space (not counting the linear space thunk, `f(0), f(1), ..., f(n-1)` at the left edge ).

Much worse would be

```
f n acc = concat [ f (n-1) $ map (r +) $ f (n-1) acc | r <- acc]
```

or in `do`-notation,

```
f n acc = do
  r <- acc
  f (n-1) $ map (r+) $ f (n-1) acc
```

because there is extra forcing due to information dependency. Similarly, if the bind for a given monad were a strict operation.

Comment: Yes, but how can we tell in a general case when it evaporates and when not? That's the whole point of the question.

Comment: I guess we have to inline the bind definition and analyze the result. I think laziness is more important here, as is usual in Haskell.

Comment: Will Ness - if the "tail recursion modulo cons" optimization is implemented only for (certain) Prolog's and not generally implemented for functional languages or by GHC, there isn't much pedagogical value discussing whether a Haskell function is in the "tail recursive modulo cons" form. This muddies up the discussion of tail recursion / tail call optimization rather than elucidates it.

Comment: @stephentetley It doesn't have to be implemented specially in Haskell; laziness gives it to us for free.

Comment: @stephentetley also, I wasn't talking about optimization. Whether the optimization is employed or not, that code is still TRMC. And under lazy evaluation no optimization is necessary, as long as the "cons" in question (i.e. the constant-space computation before the recursive call) does not force the recursive call prematurely.